# Button css is not work on mac but working on chrome windows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

here is the MAC screen shot:- https://prnt.sc/Mo8lt0lYhvGq

here is the window screen shot :- https://prnt.sc/PfHoW2DPD83f

My problem is that on mac button css is not apply. but on window it's work fine can you someone please help me on this.

```css
.why-talk-about-us .talk-about-us-btn {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #F1666E;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    color: #EB5F6A;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Gotham;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<section class="why-talk-about-us">
    <div class="why-talk-about-us-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 order-2 order-lg-1">
                    <div class="title-nd-text-wrapper">
                        <h4 class="talk-text-wrapper">Why is everyone talking about US?</h4>
                        <div class="talk-text-description">
                            <h5 class="third-section-description">
                                hello world
                            </h5>
                            <div><button class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-primary talk-about-us-btn">Sign Up for Free</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 order-1 order-lg-2">
                    <div class="fun-feature-img text-center">
                        <img src="images/r-1.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is the css really hanging there without a `style` wrapper

Comment: Have you take a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137085/flexbox-code-working-on-all-browsers-except-safari-why